# textarea font-size not changing on screen resize with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

jQuery Code

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){

    if ($(window).width() <= 800) { 
        $('textarea').css("font-size", "20x");
    } else {
        $('textarea').css("font-size", "30x");
    }

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ga5Gf/)

I want to make text in the text area smaller when the window width is *less than 800px*. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: because you have a typo, its `px` not `x`

Answer (score 6):

Why jquery when you can do this with pure CSS? I am providing one because you've tagged your question as CSS

Am using a [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) query here, which on resize will apply the relevant styles to your `textarea`

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    textarea {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ga5Gf/1/) *(Resize the window to see the effect)*

Comment: is the `all` necessary? i tested this and it worked with just `(max-width: 800px)`

Answer (score 4):

You have used `20x`, perhaps you were after `20px`? To set the `font-size` in pixels.